# ListLinePlot hides Inset at the edge

Tags: plotting, graphics, inset

I try to put a big letter 'T' at the bottom of the plot. However, it cannot go beyond the axis. For some other purpose I need those `Frame` settings. Even if one comments out them, the 'T' is still obviously incomplete, albeit a bit longer.

```
ListLinePlot[Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100}]], PlotStyle -> Blue,
  Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
 FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Blue, Automatic, Red}, LabelStyle -> Large,
  Epilog -> Inset[Style["T", 50], ImageScaled[{0.5, 0.11}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the option `PlotRangeClipping -> False`:

```
ListLinePlot[Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100}]], 
  PlotStyle -> Blue,
  Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
  FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Blue, Automatic, Red}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  LabelStyle -> Large, 
  Epilog -> Inset[Style["T", 50], ImageScaled[{0.5, 0.11}]]]
```

[image]